How to Securely Index Specific Elements from a Secret-Shared Vector Using a Binary Vector?
I am currently exploring a specific problem in secret sharing, which involves securely indexing elements specified by another binary secret-shared vector $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ from a secret-shared vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. In $\mathbf{s}$, each element is either $[0]$ or $[1]$, and we are only interested in the positions where $\mathbf{s}$ is $[1]$, with the total number of non-zero elements in $\mathbf{s}$ being permissible to reveal.
For example, let $\mathbf{I}$ be the vector of indices of all elements in $\mathbf{s}$ that are 1. If $\mathbf{x} = [1, 2, 3, 4]$ and $\mathbf{s} = [0, 1, 0, 1]$, then $\mathbf{I} = [1, 3]$. The final result should be $\mathbf{r} = [\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{I}_0}, \mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{I}_1}] = [\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_3] = [2, 4]$.
My initial approach is in two steps:

Securely obtaining the index vector $[\mathbf{I}]$: that is, obtaining a set of secret-shared indices $[\mathbf{I}] = [[i_1], [i_2], \ldots]$, where $i$ indicates the positions of 1s in $\mathbf{s}$.
Using these secret-shared indices to access the corresponding elements in $[\mathbf{x}]$.

For step 2, there have been some discussions, for example at "shared" variant of 1-out-of-N oblivious transfer, and related research in CCS21 paper Oblivious Linear Group Actions and Applications.
For the first step, how can we implement it without revealing the specific distribution of 0s and 1s in $\mathbf{s}$? If $\mathbf{s}$ has $k$ non-zero elements, the challenge in step 1 seems to be how to obliviously select these $k$ elements.
Is my approach overly complex? Are there any simplified methods or existing works that could be referred to? I am very much looking forward to your opinions and suggestions!
Any answers and discussions are highly welcome! Thank you!
